# Diminishing velocity range or?

Tags: phrase-requests

I am writing scientific paper and try to explain to reviewers that the range of velocities is getting smaller(2820-5620,then 3000-5400). How to say this in a proper manner?

Comment: "The range of observed velocities narrows" may do fine, but without any details it's hard to say.

Comment: @Jakub Thanks,I wanted to say that the range narrows at every iteration.

Comment: Or even "the range of velocities gets smaller" (very similar to the way you expressed it here). What is "a proper manner" other than that it is understandable?

Comment: The range *reduces, contracts, narrows, falls, lessens, drops, gets smaller, decreases,...* It's all a matter of opinion and *exact* context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the range of velocities **decreases** or *becomes lower & lower* or *lower each time*. However it depends if this decreasing is constant at each occurence...

Comment: Is substituting 'decreases or becomes lower ...' for 'is getting smaller'  worthy of an answer on ELU? I'll down-vote next time I visit; this might just be worthy of a 'comment'.